# on Mac OS X, I got "implicit entry/start for main executable" ---- Using: gfortran -o linker

Tags: linker, fortran, gfortran

My code is in Fortran 77, and I am using the latest gfortran package installed with brew about mid Feb. 2020. The code is quite extensive. Looks like the compiler is OK with the code:

```
gfortran -c main.for
gfortran - Sub1.for
```

etc; all worked, and created the object files main.o, Sub1.o etc.
However, upon linking,

```
gfortran -o main.o Sub1.o Sub2.o ---- MyLib.a
```

(expecting an automatically named executable) I got insteadthe error/exit message:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

What was my cardinal sin here?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. You really need to show us your code or some other short code that reproduces the problem. It is really necessary. See also [mcve]. Also, you must show the complete set of commands and no *"etc."*. Does the compiler correctly compile simple programs?

Comment: @MikeKinghan This looks like it might be it, I wouldn't hesitate to put in i an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This sketched command:

```
gfortran -o main.o Sub1.o Sub2.o ---- MyLib.a
```

requests `gfortran` to link the object files `Sub1.o`, `Sub2.o` with libraries `...MyLib.a`
and output an executable called `main.o`.

`main.o` is (presumably) the previously compiled object file that contains
the entry point of the program, but you have clobbered it to output the program
there. Hence the linkage failure. Instead, use:

```
gfortran -o prog main.o Sub1.o Sub2.o ---- MyLib.a
```

if you want to link a program called `prog`. Or if as you say you were:

> expecting an automatically named executable

then instead use:

```
gfortran main.o Sub1.o Sub2.o ---- MyLib.a
```

and the automatically named executable with be `a.out`

Comment: Dear Mike, Thanks. No, I first tried the "gfortran -o Prog main.o sub1.o etc--- and got all the errors. No executable. looks like the linker has no access to the built-in libraries.

Comment: Hi. If `gfortran` could not find needed libraries it have said so
before any undefined symbol error. I would say [mcve] needed,
including the build command(s) and their output verbatim.

Comment: @MabarOne The problem as per that comment no longer resembles the question,
but my answer is valid for the question as posted. It looks like
you asked a question about an unsuccessful attempt to solve your
problem rather than about the problem itself. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61815454/edit)
your question to express the specific problem you really want solved, in the form of a [mcve],
then I will delete my irrelevant answer and someone may write another one.

Comment: Dear Mike, right. I replaced a Block Data statement by "Main" and possibly got into another problem, where x86_64 libraries may be missing. I will Edit and revert.